# OpenCV Python best thresholding for document photos with varying light

Tags: python, opencv

**Thank you for your time dear reader,**

i´m trying to implement a document scanner in Python/OpenCV but im struggling with varying lights in the image. 
Im hoping that maybe some kind soul can at least point me in the right direction because I have no concrete clue how I could improve it - if that is possible or known at all.

Im using otsus binarization for thresholding:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

My results so far are pretty good:
[image: results so far]

But for difficult lighting with either two bright/dark areas or one bright - one dark area for instance (this is a crass example) it fails:
[image]

Playing around with Gimp curves sometimes gets me clear edges - maybe there is a best practice how to tackle this problem that I dont know of?
I played around with the code a lot but got no real progress by combining hierarchy / chain approx / approxpolydp epsilon methods etc.

My current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import sys

# zero at the end reads black white
img = cv.imread(sys.argv[1],0)
blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
# find normalized_histogram, and its cumulative distribution function
hist = cv.calcHist([blur],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
hist_norm = hist.ravel()/hist.max()
Q = hist_norm.cumsum()
bins = np.arange(256)
fn_min = np.inf
thresh = -1
for i in range(1,256):
    p1,p2 = np.hsplit(hist_norm,[i]) # probabilities
    q1,q2 = Q[i],Q[255]-Q[i] # cum sum of classes
    b1,b2 = np.hsplit(bins,[i]) # weights
    # finding means and variances
    m1,m2 = np.sum(p1*b1)/q1, np.sum(p2*b2)/q2
    v1,v2 = np.sum(((b1-m1)**2)*p1)/q1,np.sum(((b2-m2)**2)*p2)/q2
    # calculates the minimization function
    fn = v1*q1 + v2*q2
    if fn < fn_min:
        fn_min = fn
        thresh = i

# find otsu's threshold value with OpenCV function
ret, otsu = cv.threshold(blur,0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)

cv.imwrite('otsu.jpg',otsu)

_, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(otsu, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

def biggestRectangle(contours):
    biggest = None
    max_area = 0
    indexReturn = -1
    for index in range(len(contours)):
            i = contours[index]
            area = cv.contourArea(i)
            if area > 100:
                peri = cv.arcLength(i,True)
                approx = cv.approxPolyDP(i,0.1*peri,True)
                if area > max_area: #and len(approx)==4:
                        biggest = approx
                        max_area = area
                        indexReturn = index
    return indexReturn

indexReturn = biggestRectangle(contours)
hull = cv.convexHull(contours[indexReturn])
orig = cv.imread(sys.argv[1])
cv.imwrite('hola.jpg',cv.drawContours(orig, [hull], 0, (0,255,0),3))
```

The biggest rectangle code I copied from here:
[How to detect document from a picture in opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056592/how-to-detect-document-from-a-picture-in-opencv)

All credits to monic! (accepted answer)

Comment: One thing you can try is to generate multiple images with different properties (size, dpi) as a form of pre-proccesing. What I mean is taking in your input file, then creating a 2x larger, 2.5x larger,etc and just finding which one yields the best results. I'm not sure if you're intent is to pass these images for OCR or something similar, but you could then verify which result is most correct (count the number of incorrect words on a page if this was an ocr application, for example). The same could be applied to the thresholding.(let me know if this needs better explanation, still a bit early)

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
My use case is auto cropping photos for the document in it - I should have stated that.

I currently cant understand how this could help but I will read about it / try it out and keep this up to date.
Thank you for the pointer!

Maybe could you explain or point to sources as to why the thresholding will be different on different image sizes?
I imagine the recognition edge to be the same?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to achieve this would be to use color Masks but in HSV so that it stays focused on the color and not on the brightness/contrast.
Keep in mind that OpenCV encodes HSV with those ranges:

```
H: 0 - 180
S: 0 - 255
V: 0 - 255
```

Here is how I would do it:

```
# Convert your image to HSV
imgHsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

# Define lower/upper color
lower = np.array([0, 0, 180])
upper = np.array([180, 20, 255])

# Check the region of the image actually with a color in the range defined below
# inRange returns a matrix in black and white
bw = cv2.inRange(imgHsv, lower, upper)
```

Comment: Awesome Idea! I will try it out right now and answer. Thank you.

Comment: The first result looks veeeery promising :)
I´ll check out how to get the best contour for this now.

https://ibb.co/jJ2YKS

Comment: Maybe you can use both technique one after the other ? :)

Comment: Its getting better and better but I need some more time to tweak it. As soon as I have good code I´ll post an update / the code.